# MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount,token<-????) from where can I get token

Tags: azure

I'm trying to implement Microsoft authentication for a mobile app that connect to a Azure mobile back end service, I created a  MobileServiceUser user; then I tried to use the method LoginAsync and already choosed the Micorosft Provider, the question is from where can I get the token value

user = await App.Client.LoginAsync( MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount,token<-????);

I try to get info about that

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever got an answer to this question but you get the token from a client managed authentication.  You independently use each of the provider API (Facebook, Google, Microsoft, LinkedIn, etc.) and then when you authenticate it using OAuth, you will get a token back.  Then you pass the token into the LoginAsync call.

Here's some sample code:

```
                    auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
             clientId: "MyAppId",  // For Facebook login, for configure refer http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/register-identity-provider-for-new-oauth-application/
             scope: "",
             authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"), // These values do not need changing
             redirectUrl: new Uri("http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html")// These values do not need changing

// After facebook,google and all identity provider login completed 
                    auth.Completed += Auth_Completed;

    private async void Auth_Completed(object sender, Xamarin.Auth.AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsAuthenticated)
        {

string token = e.Account.Properties["access_token"];
           }
    }
```

You then pass this token in the LoginAsync method.